# Ordered Logit Model with Confusion Matrix

Tags: r

I need the R code which can do a ordered logit model and also give the confusion matrix as well.(helpful for validation part).

I have 6 categorical dependent variables, so I am going for this model.

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible exemple, like the structure of your data at least. Otherwise you let all the work being done by other. Also, you are saying that you have categorical dependant variables, but if your independant variable is continuous, a simple linear regression is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

## Download dataset wine quality from UCI machine learning repository

```
wine <- read.csv("winequality-white.csv", sep = ";")
wine$quality <- factor(ifelse(wine$quality < 5, 0,ifelse(wine$quality > 6, 2, 1)))
set.seed(7644)
wine_sampling_vector <- createDataPartition(wine$quality, p =
0.80, list = FALSE)
wine_train <- wine[wine_sampling_vector,]
wine_test <- wine[-wine_sampling_vector,]
```

You can use the following code for ordered response variable

```
library(MASS)
wine_model <- polr(quality ~ ., data = wine_train, Hess = T)
summary(wine_model)
wine_predictions <- predict(wine_model, wine_train)

mean(wine_predictions == wine_train$quality)
```

For calculating confusion matrix

```
table(predicted = wine_predictions,actual = wine_train$quality)
```

Comment: What is `wine_train` object?

Comment: We have to create wine_train and wine_test first based on our preference if we want to dataset 70:30 or 60:40

Comment: Please make your answer reproducible.

Comment: when I m trying to use the code for confusion matrix...m getting this error--

Comment: m geeting the below mentioned error while trying to use the confusion matriz code---"all arguments must have the same length"

Comment: check if predictions vector and response testing variable have the same length.